# Could the community provide critiques on my method for picking features for modeling?

Tags: modeling, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I just started a new job that is a bit more stats heavy than my old DS job. In my old gig I was mainly in the domain of scraping, descriptive statistics, visualizations, dashboards, etc. So I'm having to brush off the old stats knowledge.

I have acquired some new data and my boss wants to know how it pertains to our existing models. Generally speaking (there is some variation in my approach depending on the data) what I'm doing so far is 1) running correlations between the features I engineered and the outcome variables of interest 2) running a saturated linear model that includes all predictors that attained a correlation coefficient of 0.1 or higher 3) running bivariate linear models for each predictor 4) calculating AIC for each bivariate model. I create an easy to read chart with the scores and where a feature scores highly on two or more out of the four metrics I visually inspect the data with a scatterplot overlaid with a loess curve and possibly some histograms or density plots of the underlying data. I then provide a theoretical explanation for why we might be seeing what we are.

I have not attempted plugging the new data into the existing models as the models are someone else's baby and I don't want to step on toes. I'm viewing this as teeing him up for success in getting greater accuracy out of what he's already created.

Hoping you guys could provide some input on what else I could be doing or what limitations there are in my current approach.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: One limitation of your current approach is that you aren't actually collaborating with your colleague to improve the models. Coming up with theories in parallel seems esp. counterproductive.

Comment: We're having a joint meeting today but boss's orders is boss's orders and this was the task I was given to do. My colleague has his plate full so I think the idea was just to let me vet my own data. I do tend to agree with you that at it's best data science is a collaborative effort and it would be better if we were working hand in hand.

Comment: `boss's orders is boss's orders` [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF1WsYZ94Es&t=3180s) line from a keynote is worth hearing. $//$ That keynote also addresses feature selection in general and is mostly against doing so.

Comment: Actually I think you would get more useful feedback about the situation you are in on the Workplace SE. Otherwise the approach you've outlined is unlikely to lead to reproducible discoveries and that won't make your boss happy either. There are lots of threads about feature selection on CV that you can learn a lot from.